# How to pass a CLOB parm to a DB2 stored procedure from Squirrel SQL client?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a DB2 stored procedure on ibm i/iseries/AS400. It accepts one input parm. Parm type is CLOB. I am trying to call that stored procedure from Squirrel and I keep getting string too long. I have a XML of more than 50000 bytes to be passed to the stored proc. It is failing even before calling the stored procedure.

How to pass a CLOB from Squirrel?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Since there are no CLOB literals, and character literals are limited to 32K bytes only, you can only handle larger CLOB values programmatically.

Comment: I would think you could pass a file name or use a webservice.

Comment: pass with OS as file.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a global variable of type CLOB and use that to pass your data to the sroted proc

```
CREATE VARIABLE my_variable CLOB
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcvariable.htm

```
set my_variable = 'large amount of text...'
call my_procedure(my_variable);
```